# Add CIFilter overlay over UIImage

Tags: ios, sdk, cifilter

I have the following code that puts a blur over my UIImage. After the blur is put over the UIImage, I would also like a black screen at opacity 75% put over the UIImage, and then combine these two effects (blur and black screen) into one UIImage.

Thank you in advance!

```
CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
                        [gaussianBlurFilter setDefaults];
                        [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[bgPicture CGImage]] forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
                        [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:@0.7 forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];
                        CIImage *outputImage = [gaussianBlurFilter outputImage];
                        CIContext *context  = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
                        CGRect rect = [outputImage extent];
                        rect.origin.x   += (rect.size.width - bgPicture.size.width ) / 2;
                        rect.origin.y   += (rect.size.height - bgPicture.size.height) / 2;
                        rect.size   = bgPicture.size;

                        CGImageRef cgimg    = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:rect];
                        UIImage *image  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
                        CGImageRelease(cgimg);
                        _profilePhotos[username] = image;
```

Tried this (don't know for which value I am plugging in UIColor):

```
CIImage* filterInputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];

                        CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIConstantColorGenerator"];
                        [filter setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:.75] forKey:kCIInputColorKey];
                        [filter setValue:filterInputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

                        CIImage* filterOutputImage = filter.outputImage;

                        CIContext* ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
                        CGImageRef createdImage = [ctx createCGImage:filterOutputImage fromRect:filterOutputImage.extent];

                        UIImage* outputImages = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:createdImage];

                        _profilePhotos[username] = outputImages;
```

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble with? Do you understand how to combine filters?

Comment: Oh, sorry, one more question: what does "combine" mean here?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just don't know how to use CIFilter to add a 75% opacity black screen over the UIImage *image.

Comment: By combine I mean have in the end a UIImage that I can lets say load into a UIImageView.

Comment: CIConstantColorGenerator will give you your 75% opacity black screen. Then use a CICategoryCompositeOperation to blend that with the original image.

Comment: So is the problem that you don't know how to get a UIImage out of a CIFilter operation?

Comment: No, per your last comment before this, I don't know how to use this in code.

Comment: Sorry to be persistent but I'm still unclear: is the problem that you don't know how to combine CIFilters into a series?

Comment: No. The problem is I don't know how to use CIConstantColorGenerator to get the black screen at 75% and I don't know how to use CICategoryCompositeOperation to combine that with the original image.

Comment: Did you look at the CIConstantColorGenerator documentation and try it?

Comment: I'm not worried. But it shouldn't be necessary to write your code for you. CIFilters are very well documented. So if you understand how to flow the output from one filter to form an input of another filter, you are all set to try to construct your overall filter. If you do _not_ understand how to do that, I can show you.

Comment: Well, it seems I've already explained this pretty well here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_cifilter_and_ciimage - Look at the discussion and examples, and especially, in those examples, how (1) I use the output of one filter as the input of another filter, and (2) I ultimately call `createCGImage:fromRect:` to produce the actual image that goes into the interface.

Comment: That should get you started and then you should be able to experiment on your own. CIFilters are very easy and are a lot of fun to play with.

Comment: That code throws an exception for not the right info.

Answer (score 0):

Apple released a category on UIImage that does just that, and it does it with one line of code:

```
UIImage *newImage = [image applyBlurWithRadius:0.7 tintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:.75] saturationDeltaFactor:0.0 maskImage:nil];
```

There's even a helper method that adds a dark tint:

```
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
```

and one that takes a tint color and puts it at 60%:

```
- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;
```

It's on github here: https://github.com/codefellows/sea-b4-ios/tree/master/UIImageEffects

Comment: Are you sure that `Apple` released it?